# Can we determine the divisibility of a polynomial by another polynomial from their roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I had this small doubt. Is a polynomial divided by another polynomial if the set of roots of one polynomial is the subset of the set of roots of the other polynomial?

Comment: $x$ and $x^2$ have the same set of roots, but one of them does not divide the other.

Comment: "The set of roots" is actually ambiguous: The set of roots of $x^2+1$ in the field $\Bbb Q$ is the empty set, but the set of roots of $x^2+1$ in the field $\Bbb C$ is $\{i, -i\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main points you forget to refer to -

- *multiplicity* of a root - For example, $p(x)=x-1$ has a root $1$ with multiplicity $1$, but $p(x)=(x-1)^2$ has multiplicity $2$.
- *reducibility* of the polynomial - For example, the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible (and has no roots) over the real numbers.

You can fix your claim in the following manner -

If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two polynomials such that:

- both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are completely reducible to linear factors
- every root of $p(x)$ is a root of $q(x)$, where the multiplicity in $q$ is higher

Then $p(x)$ is dividing $q(x)$.

Comment: Are complex roots counted too or only real roots?

Comment: Depends on the field you are working on. I wasn't specific on purpose, this claim is true in any field. But yes, if you work over the complex numbers (which is an algebraically closed filed, i.e., any polynomial is reducible to linear factors) the the first bullet in the corrected claim is always true.